# How to call a local webservice in a .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How do I a webservice located on a normal .aspx page?

I have a local project where I am able to call local .asmx webservices from a ajax call. It works perfect. But I cant create a webservice on the same page in the code behind. Example if i want to call a HelloWorld() webservice located in the codebehind in the customers.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as static and decorate it with a [WebMethod] attribute.
Example -

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetData(string param)
{   
// your code goes here
}
```

This way, you will be able to call your method using a POST request through AJAX call -

```
yourpage.aspx/GetData
```

However, if you want to use GET, decorate it further with ScriptMethod tag and provide the details on request type.

```
[WebMethod()]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public static string GetData(string param)
{   
// your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done that. But it is not that. What really pussles me is, that I have been able to call webservices before from the frontend to the codebehind  (example customer.aspx  to webservice in customer.aspx.cs). But for some it does not react now.

Comment: What error do you see? Please update your questions with more details so that me or somone can help you.

Comment: There are none errors.Not from the frontend, not from the backend. If I in my ajax call in my flow.aspx calls this url: "flow.aspx/HelloWorld", nothing happens. But when I change the code to url: "MyWebService.asmx/HelloWorld, then everything works. I have tried to trace the call in the codebehind, and I can see, that the codebehind webservice in flow.aspx are not even called.

Comment: And the HelloWorld code in MyWebService and flow.aspx are the same.  [WebMethod]
        public static  string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

Comment: Are you using a POST call to call your service using aspx? Use developer tools to check the response to your ajax call.